# DownloadStringAsync blocks thread for 14 seconds on first call

Tags: c#, webclient

This only happens on one of my machines. I think it's an environment configuration problem. All machines run ESET Smart Security software firewall. Any ideas?

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

namespace Test
{
    static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            bool exit = false;
            WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            DateTime before = DateTime.Now;
            wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://74.125.95.147"), "First"); // IP Address of google, so DNS requests don't add to time.
            wc.DownloadStringCompleted += delegate(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(e.UserState + " Call: " + (DateTime.Now - before));

                if ((string)e.UserState == "First")
                {
                    before = DateTime.Now;
                    wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://74.125.95.147"), "Second");
                }
                else
                    exit = true;
            };

            /*
             * 
             * Output:
             * 
             * First Call: 00:00:13.7647873
             * Second Call: 00:00:00.0740042
             * 
             */

            while (!exit)
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This might be due to Automatic Proxy Detection. Any change if you set WebClient.Proxy to GlobalProxySelection.GetEmptyWebProxy? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.proxy.aspx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.globalproxyselection.getemptywebproxy.aspx

Comment: Yep, that fixed it. Thanks!

First Call: 00:00:00.1680096
Second Call: 00:00:00.0400023

Comment: @dtb, add that as an answer.  It deserves an up-vote or two.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your machine is configured to perform *Automatic Proxy Detection*.

You can disable it here:

[image: Screenshot]

Alternatively, you can manually override the proxy used by the WebClient. Set the [WebClient.Proxy Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.proxy.aspx) to `null` to specify that no proxy should be used. Any explicit proxy setting disables Automatic Proxy Detection.

```
client.Proxy = null;
```

However, you should offer the user the option to configure a proxy in your application in this case, because some users are required to use a proxy when accessing the Web.

Comment: Since GlobalProxySelection is deprecated just set Proxy to null
Also, to do this globally, WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = null;

Comment: Is there a downside to doing this?  If this is in client software, and the client is using a proxy, will the request fail?