# WebClient.DownloadString takes about 15 seconds when first called

Tags: c#, webclient

```
string url = "http://google.com/index.html";
WebClient client = new WebClient();
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();
string text = client.DownloadString(url);
sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed);
```

Stopwatch says `DownloadString` method takes 13-15 seconds when first called, but repeated calls take sensible amounts of time. How does this happen and how do I fix it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [.NET - DownloadStringAsync blocks thread for 14 seconds on first call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3128563/net-downloadstringasync-blocks-thread-for-14-seconds-on-first-call)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There may be a couple of things that would cause a delay on the first call such as detecting proxy settings.  Try setting the proxy to null:

```
client.Proxy = null;
```

Comment: @user1306322 be sure to read the other answer; there's a reason for that delay. You could be making it impossible for some users to use your program if you just set that to null. Unless this is just an internal tool,, of course.

Answer (score 9):

Your machine is configured to perform Automatic Proxy Detection.

You can disable it here:

[image: Screenshot]

Alternatively, you can manually override the proxy to be used by the WebClient; `null` means no proxy:

```
client.Proxy = null;
```

However, you should offer the user to configure a proxy in your application in this case, because some users have to use a proxy when accessing the Web.