# UI is freezed for 5 seconds when async button is clicked at the first time

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library

is it okay when UI is freezed for 5 seconds,  when a button is clicked at first time? I mean when I click the button to load content from website, then I cannot move the window for 5 seconds.

My code looks like this:

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{            
    var html = await GetHtmlAsync("http://msdn.microsoft.com"); 
    MessageBox.Show(html.Substring(0, 10));
}


public async Task<string> GetHtmlAsync(string url)
{
    var webClient = new WebClient();
    return await webClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync(url);
}
```

However, if I click the above button the second time or click other `async` buttons, then there is no UI freezing.

So is it okay when UI is freezed for 5 seconds,  when a button is clicked at first time?

Comment: Be more precise. It is ok for the results to be delayed, not for the UI to freeze. How do you establish that it is frozen?

Comment: Try to change the `async` call to `var html = await Task.Run(AsyncFoo);` ?

Comment: @HenkHolterman I mean when I click the button to load content from website, then I cannot move the window for 5 seconds.

Comment: @Fabjan yeah, if I use `var html = await Task.Run(AsyncFoo);` then there is no UI freezing. Is it possible to achieve the same result without using `Task.Run()`?

Comment: It shouldn't happen - make sure this is an mcve. That means, create a scrap project with _only_ this code and see if it demonstrates the problem. We should not be looking at a fragment of a much larger program.

Comment: @Fabjan - that is a horrible brute force approach. Maybe it will be needed but the OP should  look for other options first.

Comment: @HenkHolterman By all means I'm not suggesting it as a solution. It's merely a small test... It's weird though that `DownloadStringTaskAsync` is blocking the thread.

Comment: It shouldn't. And therefore I'm not ruling out `new WebClient`, that is a strange class.

Comment: @StepUp As an aside: you could remove `async` keyword from method signature and return a `Task` object directly - `return webClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync(url);`

Comment: @HenkHolterman  I see that it should work okay. However, I've created a scrap project with only this code and problem is always occurred, but  only when I click the button at the first time.

Comment: @StepUp Maybe you've some stuff not related to this in the UI that is initializing and blocking the thread ?

Comment: OK, try creating a single WebCLient in the constructor or OnLoad. Just a hunch.

Comment: @Fabjan no, just this code and nothing more.

Comment: @HenkHolterman yeah, I've created a single WebCLient in the constructor, but there is still some UI freezing for 5 seconds.

Comment: @Fabjan  `As an aside: you could remove async keyword from method signature and return a Task object directly - return webClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync(url);` I've tried it, but there is still some UI freezing for 5 seconds.

Comment: Yes, 'eliding async' is a small optimization but it couldn't have helped here.

Comment: It is not the async mechanism that is blocking you here, it is WebClient and/or your network layer.

Comment: See for instance [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10568321/60761), I think you have the same problem  Also worth a try: HttpClient. Use it as a singleton.

Comment: When it freezes, press pause in the debugger.... what's it doing?

Comment: @HenkHolterman please, write your reply to use `HttpClient`, and I'll mark as answer. You are right. Now UI is not freezed when I click at the button at the first time.

Comment: You can post a self-answer... I was just guessing. Maybe somenody comes along to tell us why HttpClient does better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `HttpClient` is the way to go but let's look at code.

Pulling the code for the [corefx source](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/deee13b99d441cf1906397c54d0c5afcf8385d92/src/System.Net.Requests/src/System/Net/HttpWebResponse.cs). If you're actually getting a `HttpWebRespone` this snippet may point to the issue your seeing.

```
public override Stream GetResponseStream()
{
    CheckDisposed();
    return _httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There could be some caching.  Try another URL each call.  But with await it should not be blocking.

I tested and I have no lag.  I would start a fresh client.  Something strange is going on.

Put in some Stopwatch Debug to try and figure where the lag is.

```
private async void btnURLclick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    var html = await GetHtmlAsync("http://msdn.microsoft.com");
    Debug.WriteLine($"btn {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}");
    MessageBox.Show(html.Substring(0, 10));

}
public async Task<string> GetHtmlAsync(string url)
{
    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    var webClient = new WebClient();
    Debug.WriteLine($"taskA {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}");
    return await webClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync(url);
}
```

Comment: This will not tell you what part is freezing.

Comment: The OP has already established that it is the `DownloadStringTaskAsync()` call...  We have eliminated `new WebClient()` , that wasn't to likely anyway.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I am not seeing where that is established.   It is not going to hurt to get some numbers.   Moving on.

Answer (score -1):

That's probably due to some communications initialization. Try this:

```
public async Task<string> GetHtmlAsync(string url)
{
    await Task.Delay(1).ConfigureAwait(false);
    var webClient = new WebClient();
    return await webClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync(url).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Comment: Then better use `Task.Yield`, or directly `Task.Run`

Comment: @KevinGosse, can you use `ConfigureAwait` with `Task.Yield`?